# Rotate dendrogram plotted with R plotly plot_dendro

Tags: r, plotly, dendrogram

I have this species `ape` `phylo` tree object:

```
species.phylo <- ape::read.tree(text="(Platypus:0.13,((((Koala:0.06,Wallaby:0.06):0.013,Tasmanaian_devil:0.067):0.002,Opposum:0.07):0.042,((Armadillo:0.078,Sloth:0.078):0.028,(((Rabbit:0.1,(((Guinea_pig:0.07,Chinchilla:0.07):0.005,(Naked_mole-rat:0.06,Damarland_mole-rat:0.058):0.02):0.03,(Jerboa:0.09,(Blind_mole-rat:0.09,((((Chinese_hamster:0.05,Golden_hamster:0.05):0.016,Deer_mouse:0.064):0.003,Prairie_vole:0.07):0.01,(Rat:0.063,Mouse:0.061):0.017):0.012):0.01):0.007):0.004):0.001,(Mouse_lemur:0.08,(Tarsier:0.08,((Marmoset:0.03,Mas_night_monkey:0.025):0.023,((((((Bonobo:0.003,Chimpanzee:0.002):0.0043,Human:0.0067):0.002,Gorilla:0.0086):0.0085,Orangutan:0.017):0.0027,Gibbon:0.02):0.011,(Green_monkey:0.012,((Sooty_mangabey:0.006,Baboon:0.0067):0.001,(Macaque:0.003,Pig-tailed_macaque:0.004):0.004):0.004):0.02):0.02):0.03):0.0006):0.02):0.0001,((European_hedgehog:0.1,Common_shrew:0.11):0.00098,(Little_brown_bat:0.09,((Cat:0.065,(Dingo:0.001,Dog:0.001):0.06):0.015,((Dolphin:0.069,(Pig:0.077,((Goat:0.01,Sheep:0.01):0.017,Cow:0.027):0.05):0.0001):0.01,(Horse:0.006,Donkey:0.0067):0.076):0.004):0.0017):0.015):0.0001):0.0001):0.014):0.006);")
```

Which I then convert to a `dendrogram` object:

```
species.dend <- ape::chronopl(species.phylo,lambda=1) %>% phylogram::as.dendrogram()
```

And then plot using `R`'s `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)
plot_dendro(species.dend, height = 600, width=600) %>% 
  hide_legend() %>% 
  highlight(persistent = F, dynamic = F)
```

And it comes out with the root pointing right and leaves pointing left, and pretty squished:
[image]

So my questions are:

1. How to rotate it 180 degrees so that the root will point left and leaves point right?
2. How to stretch out the branches so that it is not so squished?

Comment: Have you tried ggtree (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggtree.html)?

Comment: Plotly uses dendextend for dendrogram manipulation. You may wish to have a look at ggdend from dendextend and see if that solves your issue (since you can then use ggplotly on the output): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#ggplot2-integration